# Query regarding Worklight upgrade from 5.0.5 to 5.0.6.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are planning to perform an upgrade of Worklight Server v5.0.5 to v5.0.6.2.

Our current Worklight Server setup is on Linux machine and we want to perform a silent installation.

We checked this link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038300

and not able to understand the process clearly. We had already downloaded the Worklight Server v5.0.6.2 fix from fixcentral.

Question : Could you please let us know if only v5.0.6.2 fix is enough to perform the upgrade or we need to install v5.0.6.0 first and then install the fix seperately ?

Question : Also could you please help in preparing the response file for the silent mode installation ?

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

For the silent install file, this page of the WL 6.1 documenttion should help you: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp
It contains a link to a zip file of silent install files that includes install and upgrades for 5.0.6.x. You should use the files 5.0.6\upgrade.xml

> > is enough to perform the upgrade or we need to install v5.0.6.0 first and then install the fix seperately

Installation Manager must know the repository of 5.0.6 and 5.0.6.2 to apply or install the fix pack (the 5.0.6.2 installer is an incremental installer).

From 5.0.5 to 5.0.6.2, the installer will modify the database tables. So it is important to perform a backup before running the installer, as indicated in the link in order to have a possible rollback scenario,

This step of the document you listed http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038300,
'Finish Migrating the Worklight Project ' is also very important.

And also the first step, 'Prepare for Migrating the Worklight Project'.